# Promodel Error "For <Entity> arriving at Queue: A new cycle has been scheduled to start before the current cycle will be completed!"

Tags: simulation, cycle

This error ocurres when you have set an arrival cycle and click play to run the model.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: "For  arriving at Queue: A new cycle has been scheduled to start before the current cycle will be completed!"

The problem is that the arrival cycle table is defined in hours, and the frequency is normally set in minutes, this error could be avoided by setting a higher or equal time than the maximum time set in the arribe cycle table.

i.e. if you define a cycle of 36 hours, you should put in frequency a minimum of "36 hr" or "2160" (36 x 60) by doing this your simulation shouldn't give the error.

Comment: I had this problem, no one could give me the answer, i looked it up in a book and it worked :)